# Como verificar Clases en una Lista

Tags: java, poo, lista

Tengo una lista `List<Persona> personas` de **Jugador** y **Invitado** las dos extienden de Persona. Entonces, `Jugador` tiene `String contrasena`, `int id`, `String nombre` y `Invitado` tiene `int id` e `String nombre` que hereda de Invitado. Vale.

#CODIGO:

```
  public Persona login(String n, int id, String passoword) { //si hay me devulve el jugador o un invitado, si no un null
        Iterator it = getListaPersonas().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Persona aux = (Persona) it.next();//ver si es Jugador o Invitado con getClass
            Jugador jug = (Jugador) it.next();
            Invitado invi = (Invitado) it.next();
            if(aux.getClass().equals(jug.getClass())){ //si la persona actual es un Jugador
                if(jug.getContraseña().equals(passoword) && aux.getIdentificador() == id && jug.getNombre().equals(n)) {
                    return jug;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(aux.getClass().equals(invi.getClass())) { //si la personal actual es un Invitado
                    if(invi.getIdentificador() == id && invi.getNombre().equals(n)) {
                        return invi;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Lo sé que hay un error, pero lo que quiero es verificar si la personal actual es Jugador o Invitado, así también, ver si el nombre `String n` identificación `int id` contraseña `String passoword`son iguales a este Jugador actual, si es pues le devuelvo y hago un casting arriba de mi código(no tiene que ver con esa) para guardar su contenido. Lo mismo hago con Invitado pero el no tiene contraseña. Mi duda es ¿como comparar bien y retornarlo de manera adecuada? Saludos.

Comment: y si sabe qu hay un error, porque no lo arreglas y tratamos de arreglar tu otro problema (que no entendi cual es)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber si un objeto de los que estás recorriendo es Jugador o Invitado existe un método instanceof para saber si es una instancia de una Clase:

```
for(Persona objeto: persona.getListaPersonas()) {
    if(objeto instanceof Jugador) {
        System.out.println(objeto.toString());
        System.out.println("Es un jugador");
    }
    if(objeto instanceof Invitado) {
        System.out.println(objeto.toString());
        System.out.println("Es un invitado");
    }
}
```

Lo he puesto así porque no sé cual es tu otro error pero si quieres saber si es Jugador o Invitado esto te será suficiente.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Me ha ayudado a solucionar una duda que me ayudó a solucionar otra. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplificar tu código con lo siguiente:

Crea el método `validar(nombre, id, password)` en la clase Persona, las otras dos clases deben sobreescribir ese método y cada una usará las variables que necesiten para su validación.

Jugador validará: `nombre`, `id` y `password`; e invitado: `id` y `nombre`.

Luego solo recorres la lista de personas, llamas la función validar de cada elemento y si es verdadero retornas ese objeto.

**Nota**: setters y getters omitidos por simplicidad.

```
class Persona {
    public boolean validar(String n, int id, String password){return false:}
}

class Jugador extends Persona{

    public String contraseña;
    public int id;
    public String nombre;


    @Override
    public boolean validar(String n, int id, String password) {
        return contraseña.equals(password) && this.id == id && nombre.equals(n);
    }
}

class Invitado extends Persona{

    public int id;
    public String nombre;

    @Override
    public boolean validar(String n, int id, String password) {
        return this.id == id && nombre.equals(n);
    }
}

public class Test{

    static List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String... args)  {

        Jugador j = new Jugador();
        j.contraseña = "1234";
        j.id = 1;
        j.nombre = "juan";

        Invitado i = new Invitado();
        i.id = 2;
        i.nombre = "jon";



        lista.add(j);
        lista.add(i);

    }

    public  static  Persona login(String nombre, int id, String password){

        for (Persona p : lista){
            if(p.validar(nombre,id,password))
                return p;
        }

        return  null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Los campos `nombre` y `id` pueden ir directamente en la clase padre.